# Sum up cell values in HTML table if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with three columns: item, price and a checkbox. I want to calculate the subtotal but only include the prices with a checked checkbox. The code I have so far is a mix of various bits that work on its own; however right now I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')". What am I doing wrong?

```js
function calculate() {
  const ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let subTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    let price = td[i].innerHTML;
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true)
      subTotal += price;
  }
  document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "The subtotal is " + subTotal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>T-Shirt</td>
      <td>9.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pants</td>
      <td>49.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span id="val">The subtotal is 0</span>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate subtotal</button>

</html>
```

Comment: `td` is not a collection - it's an element, because of the `[1]` you placed at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the line `td[i]` because it's not defined as the error suggests. So, consider using bare  `td` and accessing its `innerText`. It'll return a string with the value, which you have to convert to a float number with `parseFloat`. Finally, you must set the precision you want to `subTotal` so that it will print with the number of decimals you want.

```js
function calculate() {
  const ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let subTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    let price = parseFloat(td.innerText); // change here
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true)
      subTotal += price;
  }
  document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "The subtotal is " + subTotal.toFixed(2); // and set precision here
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>T-Shirt</td>
      <td>9.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pants</td>
      <td>49.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span id="val">The subtotal is: </span>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate subtotal</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is simple. You referenced the td and than you try to reference it again.

```
let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
let price = td[i].innerHTML;
```

Should be

```
const td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
const price = td.innerHTML;
```

If you use a value on the checkbox, you can just loop over the checked inputs and calculate the total using the values. No need to look up cell contents.

```js
function calculate() {
   const checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable input:checked");
   const total = Array.from(checkedInputs).reduce(function(total, cb) {
     return total + +cb.value;
  }, 0);
  document.querySelector("#val").textContent = "The subtotal is " + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>T-Shirt</td>
      <td>9.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="9.99"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pants</td>
      <td>49.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="49.99"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span id="val">The subtotal is 0</span>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate subtotal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate trhough checkbox and going up until the previous td

```js
function calculate() {
    let chckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input:checked');
    let sum = 0;
    chckboxes.forEach((itm) => {
        let val = parseFloat(itm.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML)
                sum += val;
    });

    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "The subtotal is " + sum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>T-Shirt</td>
      <td>9.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pants</td>
      <td>49.99</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span id="val">The subtotal is 0</span>
  <button onclick="javascript:calculate()">Calculate subtotal</button>

</html>
```