# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with two columns: values and checkboxes. I want to identify the smallest value with a checked checkbox. I adapted the setup from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531746/sum-up-cell-values-in-html-table-if-checkbox-is-checked), but changed the way I identify checkboxes from
`document.getElementsByTagName('input')`
to
`querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox")`. The initial way became a problem when I added an additional input field (which is why I included it below)

However, the function throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`.

What's going wrong?

```js
function smallestWeight() {
  let values = [];
  const ele = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox");
  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0, len = trs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true) {
      values.push(parseFloat(trs[i].cells[0].innerHTML));
    }
  }
}


const btn = document.getElementById("click");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  smallestWeight();
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>value</th>
      <th>include</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="include" value="include" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="include" value="include" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="include" value="include" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="include" value="include" checked></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="click">Click</button><br>
<input type="number">
```

Comment: If you gave the checkbox a value, this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Your initial answer worked, thank you. However, what do you mean by "giving the checkbox a value"? Each checkbox has `value="include"`

Comment: like value="1.1" instead of looking it up in the text.... Seems like a waste to all all the checkboxes with `value="include"` since it really does not do anything.

Comment: Also ids are singular. You should not have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Roger that, agree on removing `value` and `id`. I look it up in the text because I have three columns in total with various numbers, so I can't assign just one value to a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks at all rows in the table. You do not take into account that the first row of the table is the thead. So your table rows is one more greater than the checkboxes.

```
const trs = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
```